# Blazor WASM Virtualize request.count will always be maximum

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

```html
    <Virtualize ItemsProvider="LoadUsers" Context="user" ItemSize="87">
                                    <ItemContent>
                                        <tr id="@user.UserName">
                                            <td>@user.Index</td>
                                            <td>@user.UserName</td>
                                            <td>@user.UserId</td>
                                            <td>@user.CreatedDate</td>
                                            @if (user.UserName == $"{SD.ROLE_ADMIN}@gmail.com" || user.UserName == context.User.Identity.Name)
                                            {
                                                <td></td>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <td>
                                                    <select class="mr-2" @onchange="async(e)=> await ChangePermission(user, e)">
                                                        @foreach (var role in _accountViewModel.Roles)
                                                        {
                                                            if (role == user.Role)
                                                            {
                                                                <option value="@role" selected>@role</option>
                                                                continue;
                                                            }
                                                            <option value="@role">@role</option>
                                                        }
                                                    </select>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="async()=> await DeleteUser(user)">Delete</button>
                                                </td>
                                            }
                                        </tr>
                                    </ItemContent>
                                    <Placeholder>
                                        <tr>
                                            loading...
                                        </tr>
                                    </Placeholder>
                                </Virtualize>
```

`razor.cs` :

```cs
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
             _module = await _jSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/common.js");
            _loadedUser = new();
            _totalUsersCount = await _accountViewModel.GetUsersCount();
        }

        private async ValueTask<ItemsProviderResult<AccountViewModel.UserInfo>> LoadUsers(ItemsProviderRequest request)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{request.StartIndex} - {request.Count}");
            var numUsers = Math.Min(request.Count, _totalUsersCount - request.StartIndex);
            var users = await _accountViewModel.GetUsers(request.StartIndex, numUsers);
            _loadedUser.AddRange(users);

            return new ItemsProviderResult<AccountViewModel.UserInfo>(users, _totalUsersCount);
        }
```

Here is my code.

When it loads the page first `request.startIndex` is 0, and `request.count` is 12. After 1 second (I didn't do anything and stayed still), `request.startIndex` is 0, and `request.count` is 3900 (`_totalUserscount` max of users number)

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.